# How can I execute Python code in a virtualenv from Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, virtualenv

I am creating a Matlab toolbox for research and I need to execute Matlab code but also Python code.

I want to allow the user to execute Python code from Matlab. The problem is that if I do it right away, I would have to install everything on the Python's environment and I want to avoid this using virtualenv. The problem is that I don't know how to tell Matlab to user the virtual enviornment created.

Comment: cant you pass the full path to the virtualenv python executable?

Comment: @TalesPádua Yes, I didn't realize it, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either modify the `PATH` environment variable in MATLAB prior to calling python from MATLAB

```matlab
% Modify the system PATH so it finds the python executable in your venv first
setenv('PATH', ['/path/to/my/venv/bin', pathsep, getenv('PATH')])

% Call your python script
system('python myscript.py')
```

Or the better way would be to specify the full path to the python binary

```
system('/path/to/my/venv/bin/python myscript.py')
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in comment by @tales-pádua you may use [pyversion](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyversion.html) command to set path to Python executable you are using (before trying to call python from Matlab).

This can be automated by use of [matlabrc.m](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html) file:

```
python = '.local/bin/python';
if exist(python, 'file')
    pyversion(python)
end
```

Comment: This is supported from Matlab 2020a. The recommended command is [pyenv][1] [1]: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyenv.html